# How to populate my tableView in Swift 2 from JSON?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift2

A new programmer here. How would I populate my tableView from this JSON?
My first problem is the JSON Serialization and then plugging it in the tableView.

**Code**

```
import UIKit

class LegislatorsTableVC: UITableViewController {

// MARK: Variables & Outlets
private let cellIdentifer = "cellReuse"

// MARK: View Did Load
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Creating Congfiguration Object // Session Is Created // Getting Info/Data
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)
    let apiKey = "https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&all_legislators=true&per_page=all"

    if let url = NSURL(string: apiKey) {
        // Spawning Task To Retrieve JSON Data
        session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            // Checking For Error
            if let error = error {
                print("The error is: \(error)")
                return
            }
            // Response
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpResponse.statusCode == 200, let data = data {
                print("Status Code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                // self.JSONSerialization(data)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
} // End Of View Did Load

// JSON Serialization Function With SwiftyJSON.swift
private func JSONSerialization(data: NSData){

    // I See this Gets A Status Code 200 And Then I'm Lost.
    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]

    } catch {
        print("Error Serializing JSON Data: \(error)")
    }
} // End Of JSONSerialization



// MARK: - Table view data source
// Number Of Sections
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
} // End Of Number Of Sections

// Number Of Rows In Section
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 15
} // End Of Number Of Rows In Section

// Cell For Row At Index Path
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifer, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LegislatorTVCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.name.text = "Name"
    cell.title.text = "Title"
    cell.party.text = "Party"

    return cell
} // End Of Cell For Row At Index Path
}
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Comment: I "encrypted" the api key because the URL really works and the JSON could  contain confidential data.

Comment: If one needs to summon a mod to delete a question due to sensitive info, then do so. If that is the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Create a custom class `Person` outside the view controller

  ```
  class Person {
    var firstName = ""
    var lastName = ""
    var title = ""
    var party = ""
  }
  ```
- Create an array of `Person` in the view controller

  ```
  var people = [Person]()
  ```
- The JSON has a key `results` which contains an array of dictionaries.
  In `viewDidLoad` parse the JSON and create `Person` instances. Finally reload the table view.

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Creating Congfiguration Object // Session Is Created // Getting Info/Data
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)
    let apiKey = "https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&all_legislators=true&per_page=all"

    if let url = NSURL(string: apiKey) {
      // Spawning Task To Retrieve JSON Data
      session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        // Checking For Error
        if error != nil {
          print("The error is: \(error!)")
          return
        } else if let jsonData = data {
          do {
            let parsedJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
            guard let results = parsedJSON["results"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] else { return }
            for result in results {
              let person = Person()
              person.firstName = result["first_name"] as! String
              person.lastName = result["last_name"] as! String
              person.party = result["party"] as! String
              person.title = result["title"] as! String
              self.people.append(person)
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
              self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

          } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
          }
        }
      }).resume()
    }
  } // End Of View Did Load
  ```
- The table view delegate methods look very clear when using a custom class.
  Since `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called very often the code is quite effective.

  ```
  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return people.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifer, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LegislatorTVCell

    let person = people[indexPath.row]
    cell.name.text = person.firstName + " " + person.lastName
    cell.title.text = person.title
    cell.party.text = person.party

    return cell
  } // End
  ```

Of course I couldn't test the code but this might be a starting point.

Comment: Thank you for the help @vadian.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do is introduce a new variable to your class, for example `jsonDict` like so:

```
class LegislatorsTableVC: UITableViewController {
    var jsonDict:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>?
    // further code
```

And then - you almost got it right already - save your JSON serialization into that in your `JSONSerialization` function. (which I would rename to `parseJSON` or something like that to avoid confusion) like so:

```
do {
    jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]

} catch {
    print("Error Serializing JSON Data: \(error)")
}
```

So then you can return the right values to your `tableView data source`:

```
// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return jsonDict["your JSON key"].count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return jsonDict["your JSON key"]["items"].count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifer, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LegislatorTVCell

    let item = jsonDict["your JSON key"][indexPath.row]

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.name.text = item["name"]
    cell.title.text = item["title"]
    cell.party.text = item["party"]

    return cell
}
```

Naming is a little confusing, as I don't know the layout of your JSON, but replace `your JSON key` with your path to the data of course.

Comment: Thanks for that help. Still a little confused on what "your JSON key" should be.

Comment: An optional dictionary `[String:AnyObject]?` as data source is bad practice. Since the table view is never optional the data source is also supposed to be non-optional but could be empty. Further you have to downcast from `AnyObject` to the proper type all the time which is pretty expensive.

Comment: Well depending on the way your JSON is made up, this is where you put the key to the data that you want to disable in your tableView